# java arraylist add replace instead add

Tags: java, object, arraylist

many thanks. I'm confusing develop a academic work, (n chess queens), all recursive threads generate correct result, but i'm trying to store solution (an array of integer for columns with a number of row), in an ArrayList, but my problem is that method add() of arraylist replace contents of arraylist instead add a new , i suppose that is a instance related problem but i don't know how solve it. Sure is a silly stupid fact because my poor Java level. Really Many thanks for take a look!!.

```
package preda2.package_Preda_Reinas;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Vuelta_atras_reinas {

    ArrayList<Integer[]> vector_solucion = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public void reinas(Integer s[],Integer n,Integer k)  {                
        s[k] = 0;
        while (s[k]<= n-1) 
        {
            s[k]++;           
            if(computable(s,k))
            {              
                if(k==(n-1))
                {                    
                    vector_solucion.add(s);                    
                    System.out.println("solución encontrada: "+Arrays.toString(s));                    
                    for(int i=0;i<vector_solucion.size();i++)
                    {  
                        System.out.println("Size: "+vector_solucion.size()+" ["+i+"]"+Arrays.toString((Integer[]) vector_solucion.get(i)));
                    }                       
                }
                else reinas(s,n,k+1);
            }             
        }        
    }
    public boolean computable(Integer s[],Integer k)
      {        
          for(Integer i=0;i<=k-1;i++)
          {
            //  System.out.println("s[i] es "+s[i]+" s[k] es "+s[k]+" Math.abs(s[i]-s[k])es "+Math.abs(s[i]-s[k])+" Math.abs(i-k) es "+Math.abs(i-k));
              if(s[i] == s[k] || (Math.abs(s[i]-s[k])==Math.abs(i-k)))
                  return false;
          }
          return true;
      }    

}
```

I call function reinas from method main of other class with senteces:

```
Vuelta_atras_reinas Vuelta_atras_reinas_Bi = new Vuelta_atras_reinas();        
Integer s[]= new Integer[4];
Vuelta_atras_reinas_Bi.reinas(s,4,0);
```

And the results are:

```
solución encontrada: [2, 4, 1, 3]
Size: 1 [0][2, 4, 1, 3]
solución encontrada: [3, 1, 4, 2]
Size: 2 [0][3, 1, 4, 2] <--- It must be [2,4,1,3]
Size: 2 [1][3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're constantly adding the same, unique array to the list. So you end up with N references to the same array in the list.

You need to make a copy of the array before adding it to the list, if you want to remember all intermediate values.

Comment: Thaks for fast response, I tried to do that before, but i'm doing that badly. I do:

    Integer s_local[] = new Integer[n];
    s_local = s;
    vector_solucion.add(s_local);

Comment: That creates a new array filled with null and assigns it to a variable s_local, then discards it by assigning a reference to the original array to s_local. No copy is made at all. Google for "how to create a copy of an array in Java", click on the first link, and read.